# JS can't clean the DOM on keyup if the input is empty

Tags: javascript

i'm having problems with cleaning the dom when i use the backspace

it seems work fine at the start, after if you press the wrong key and you have to correct there are multiples lines that are cloned

[image]

as you can see in the console, the array contains only 2 elements and it is the result that I expect to have in the table.. even so, still not the result obtained

where am I wrong?

```js
const searchField = document.getElementById('search_field');
const tableOutput = document.getElementById('table_output');
const tableApp = document.getElementById('table_app');
const tbody = document.getElementById('table_body');

searchField.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value;
    if(e.key === "Backspace") {
        tbody.innerHTML = '';
        console.log(tbody.innerHTML)
       }
    tbody.innerHTML = '';
   if (searchValue.trim().length > 0) {

        tbody.innerHTML = "";
        fetch('filtered_tasks', {
            body: JSON.stringify({ searchText: searchValue }),
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            tableApp.style.display = 'none';
            tableOutput.style.display = 'table';
            if(data.length === 0) {
                tableOutput.innerHTML = 'Nessun risultato trovato';
            }else {
                data.forEach(task => {
                    if(task.delayed === 0 || task.delayed == null){
                        tableOutput.innerHTML += `
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="cell">${task.a}</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.b }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.c }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.d }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.h }</div>
                             <div class="cell"><a href="tel:${ task.i }"> ${ task.i }</a></div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                          </div>
                        `;
                    }else if (task.delayed === 1){
                        tableOutput.innerHTML += `
                           <div class="row warning-1">
                             <div class="cell">${task.a}</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.b }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.c }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.d }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.h }</div>
                             <div class="cell"><a href="tel:${ task.i }"> ${ task.i }</a></div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                          </div>
                        `;

                    }else if (task.delayed === 2){
                        tableOutput.innerHTML += `
                           <div class="row warning-2">
                             <div class="cell">${task.a}</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.b }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.c }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.d }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.h }</div>
                             <div class="cell"><a href="tel:${ task.i }"> ${ task.i }</a></div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                          </div>
                        `;
                    }else if (task.delayed > 2){
                        tableOutput.innerHTML += `
                           <div class="row warning-3">
                             <div class="cell">${task.a}</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.b }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.c }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.d }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.h }</div>
                             <div class="cell"><a href="tel:${ task.i }"> ${ task.i }</a></div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.e }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.f }</div>
                             <div class="cell">${ task.g }</div>
                          </div>
                        `;
                    }
                 })

            }
        })

   }else {
        tbody.innerHTML = null;
        tableOutput.style.display = 'none';
        tableApp.style.display = 'table';
   }
})
```

```css
.table {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    display: table;

}

.table .row {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: white;
}
.table .row:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


.table .row.header {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
}

.table .row.beige {
    background-color: beige;
}

.table .row .cell {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.table .row .cell.purple {
    background: #ad4ef0;
    color: white;
}
.table .row.warning-1 {
    background: #e2f04e!important;
}
.table .row.warning-2 {
    background: #f0ad4e!important;
}
.table .row.warning-3 {
    background: #f05c4e!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="" id="search_field" placeholder="Cerca"> 

<div class="table" id="table_app">
</div>

<div class="table output" id="table_output">
  <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell">a</div>
      <div class="cell">b</div>
      <div class="cell">c</div>
      <div class="cell">d</div>
      <div class="cell">e</div>
      <div class="cell">f</div>
      <div class="cell">g</div>
      <div class="cell">h</div>
      <div class="cell">i</div>
      <div class="cell">o</div>
      <div class="cell">p</div>
      <div class="cell">q</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="table_body">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my guess is it has nothing to do with it since you set the innerHTML of the body to an empty string in two places.  If I have to guess you have multiple fetch calls returning and writing.

Comment: @epascarello It would seem strange to me since it is the only js code that I have in the project.
Is it possible that it is executed more than once?

Comment: If you type twice two key events fire and you have two calls. That fetch code is not instant.

Comment: Indeed thats likely it. Every time you press a key a fetch call is made. If you press 2 keys in quick succession, you have no guarantee the fetch calls will return in the same order they were made. You need async control logic for this to either guarantee they are resolved in sequence, or beter yet, abort the previous fetch (if its still in flight) when a new one is made. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally i found the error

```
if(data.length === 0) {
            tableOutput.innerHTML = 'Nessun risultato trovato';
        }else {
            data.forEach(task => {
                if(task.delayed === 0 || task.delayed == null){
```

as you can see in the 2nd line i'm clearing the innerHTML of the table and not the body of the table, now it's working after change the line :

```
if(data.length === 0) {
            tbody.innerHTML = 'Nessun risultato trovato';
        }else {
            data.forEach(task => {
                if(task.delayed === 0 || task.delayed == null){
```